# Android emulator unreachable proxy on host windows

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using tor on my windows machine, it's port is 8118. Now in android emulator I want to use tor from windows host so I open **setting -> proxy** and set this [according this](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking):

[image]

But as you can see `proxy is unreachable`?

How can I use emulator under tor?

I also added host  IP address but I got `unreachable`.Additionally I do not use android studio. I just use android emulator to run react native app .

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and managed to solve it by not using Android Studio or Emulator settings at all. I deleted all proxy settings in the emulator settings and studio, then opened wifi settings in the emulator, edit the AndroidWifi -> Advanced and set my proxy there (10.0.2.2 port 8888) and that was the only thing that worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, app just hangs and shows CONNECT messages in the Fiddler console.